# Raise ranking at beginning GTA 5 online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I just started GTA online and can't do the race at the very beginning because my rank is to low and I can't do any missions until I've done this one.

How do I raise my ranking under these conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Working for a CEO or Motorclub, successfully escape the cops and Minigames (Jobs) all yield XP.

You could also do the Lamar missions marked with a yellow "LD" on the map, which yield a tiny bit of cash but also XP.